# Django 1.11 django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch:

Tags: python, django, frameworks, django-views

I've been trying to find a same question like what i want, but the question not seemed same like what i want. I still start learn about Django, Framework for python. I following a tutoial from django documentation and i get stuck when i try to learn about Generic View. i'll show my code :

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from mulai.views import IndexView, DetailView, ResultsView, votes

app_name = "start"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<choice_question_id>[0-9]+)/votes/$', votes, name='votes')

]
```

templates/detail.html

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'start:votes' question_list.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question_list %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="vote">
</form>
```

view.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'mulai/detail.html'

def votes(request, choice_pertanyaan_id):
    # return HttpResponse("votes of the question : %s." % choice_pertanyaan_id)
    question_vote = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=choice_pertanyaan_id)

    try:
        click_choice = question_vote.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'mulai/detail.html', {
            'question_vote': question_vote,
            'pesan_error': "You must select one of them choice.",
        })

    else:
        click_choice.choice_vote += 1
        click_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('practice:results', args=(question_vote.id,)))
```

And the error i got from the detail.html, and the erro is :

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'votes' not found. 'votes' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

A tree folder projecr :

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mulai
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── mulai
│   │       ├── detail.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       └── results.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── start
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: it seems that you didn't define the `votes` function in your views.

Comment: I define the vote function on view, take a look the question. i already update the question.

Comment: the id variable name in urls should be same as in view functions.

Comment: But the error not in the view, but in the urls

Comment: can you please share the file structure for your project?

Comment: I already update the question, and i add the tree of file.

Comment: i already change choice_question_id to choice_pertanyaan_id, but still error.

Answer (score 1):

This line here :

```
url(r'^(?P<choice_question_id>[0-9]+)/votes/$', votes, name='votes')
```

corresponds to

```
<form action="{% url 'start:votes' question_list.id %}" method="post">
```

The correct action should be :

```
{% url 'start:votes' choice_question_id=question_list.id %}
```

Comment: Im sorry, but it's still error. And the error is same like the last time.

Comment: ?? Your app_name should be `mulai` related to your project Structure. How is your Overall Project called `start` ? There is a problem with your Project Structure and urls loading.

Comment: i think, that's not the problem. The problem is the votes do not find on the urls file

Comment: When i try to change the app_name from 'start' to 'mulai', the result's is still give me an error.

Comment: see my answer no 2

Answer (score 0):

You are not following [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form) closely enough. In the detail view, you do not have a variable `question_list`, you have `question`. To get the choices, you loop through the question's choice set.

```
<form action="{% url 'start:votes' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
...
```

Note that your argument `choice_pertanyaan_id` in your `votes` view does not match `choice_question_id` in your URL pattern. It would be better to use `question_id` as in the tutorial.

Comment: Im sorry @Alasdair, But the error not inside a looping, but the "votes" it's not define.

Comment: The first part of my answer has nothing to do with the loop. Using `question_list.id` in the `{% url %}` tag is incorrect. If my answer doesn't fix the problem, then you'll need to update your question with more info - add the full traceback of the error message, the contents of `start/urls.py`, and update the code so that it matches your current code exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the name of your project is start. Correct ?

Simplified this would be the correct structur of your files (esp. url.py and your views)

```
├── manage.py
└── start
   ├── settings.py
   ├── urls.py
├── mulai
   ├── admin.py
   ├── models.py
   ├── templates
   ├── urls.py
   └── views.py
```

`start/urls.py` is the major urls.py. Looking basically like this :

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^mulai/', include('mulai.urls')),
```

and then in `mulai/urls.py` you define your *urls* like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<choice_question_id>[0-9]+)/votes/$', votes, name='votes')
]
```

The namespace `start` as used in your reverse would be defined in the file `start/urls.py` like this :

```
    url(r'^mulai/', include('mulai.urls', namespace='start')),
```